# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Error handling with exe

Tags: c#, sql-server

Getting error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.  The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.  (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1326)

I have an exe file of a software. When I open this `.exe` file and login with correct email or password. But system throws this error. I have been searching out in stack overflow they do not explain this error handling with exe.

Is it i will convert from exe to source cod ?

I am new I don't know better.The client ask me that you removed this error. This system developed by another developer.

I don't know what should I do ?

Thanks in advance. Who give me answer he will be appreciated by me.

Comment: Try following steps given in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci.

Comment: at that time i am decompiling exe. But many software do not give me exact code means give me code with many eror.I want to get exact code which software best for decompiling c#.net code.I have been search out or install lspy,jetbrains.dotpook or i am trying to download dotnet resolver but do not find out of them.If you know any link about the downloading of dot net resolver send me thanks.